# Docker: Two containers under same network cann't communicate

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I created two docker containers and connected them to the same network, but either of the container cannot connect to the other one.
I have tried the steps on [this page](https://maximorlov.com/4-reasons-why-your-docker-containers-cant-talk-to-each-other/#:%7E:text=Containers%20can%20only%20communicate%20with,can%20have%20multiple%20containers%20inside.), but none of the methods worked.
Anything else I can try?

```
docker run -d --name db1 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres:10-alpine
docker run -d --name db2 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres:10-alpine

docker network create myNetwork
docker network connect myNetwork db1
docker network connect myNetwork db2

# make sure that the network has 2 containers
docker inspect myNetwork

docker exec -it db1 ping db2
PING db2 (172.18.0.4): 56 data bytes
^C
--- cvat_db ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss


 docker exec -it db1route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.18.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.18.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0

#ifconfig
br-3f4022544f42: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:e5ff:fe9f:33bc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:e5:9f:33:bc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21  bytes 1164 (1.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 44  bytes 5656 (5.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:b9ff:fe47:f00c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:b9:47:f0:0c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1  bytes 28 (28.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 54  bytes 6637 (6.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: What result do you get?  PostgreSQL doesn't do anything in particular with ICMP packets; do you mean to use a client tool like `psql` instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze It doesn't matter what image I use, the ping command at the end shows 100% data loss, and I can't even ping google.com inside the container.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem: if I copy and paste the everything before `docker inspect`, I can successfully ping from `db1` to `db2`. More importantly, from inside `db1` I can `psql -h db2 -U postgres` and authenticate successfully.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for verifying that, it should not be docker network configuration issue, I'm not sure if it's the firewall or network interface issue.
The container's route shows Iface is eth0 while ifconfig does not show this network device name